# wher's the all window proc registered in windows

Tags: windows

As we can see from MSDN,we know that the same class has the same default window procedure,for example:the CEdit class have a default window procedure for all the CEdit class,but if we create an new edit window by implement the CEdit class ,we can define our window procedure to process the message passed from system.And ,for another hand,when a window is created and assigned a window procedure,the system will allocate an memory block to save some information(the address of winproc,and so on ...).These information must be stored in somewhere else.

SO,My question is:how to browse the window proc(include the proc user defined himself) or find where they are placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `HWND` refers to a data block. Call `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` to get the Window proc for that particular `hwnd`.